# PLS-00201 when executing an Oracle Database PL/SQL procedure using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to run the following code

```
import cx_Oracle

p0_ = 'NULL'
p1_ = 'NULL'
p2_ = 'NULL'
p3_ = '''OPPORTUNITY_NO'||chr(31)||'2019-ttt'
||chr(30)||'DESCRIPTION'||chr(31)||'tttttttttt'||chr(30)||
'COMPANY'||chr(31)||'1000'||chr(30)||
'BUSINESS_TYPE'||chr(31)||'New'||chr(30)||
'CUSTOMER_ID'||chr(31)||'1723'||chr(30)||
'CURRENCY_CODE'||chr(31)||'USD'||chr(30)||
'PROBABILITY'||chr(31)||'100%'||chr(30)||
'BASE_EST_OPPORTUNITY_VALUE'||chr(31)||'0'||chr(30)||
'EST_OPPORTUNITY_VALUE'||chr(31)||'0'||chr(30)||
'MAIN_REPRESENTATIVE_ID'||chr(31)||'fffffff'||chr(30)||
'SOURCE_ID'||chr(31)||'Contract Services'||chr(30)||
'OPPORTUNITY_TYPE'||chr(31)||'Formal'||chr(30)||
'STAGE_ID'||chr(31)||'Won'||chr(30)||
'START_DATE'||chr(31)||'2020-08-01-00.00.00'||chr(30)||
'EXPIRATION_DATE'||chr(31)||'2020-08-02-00.00.00'||chr(30)||
'MARKET_CODE'||chr(31)||'03'||chr(30)||
'UPDATE_OPPRTUN_LINES'||chr(31)||'FALSE'||chr(30)||
'ADDRESS_SELECTED'||chr(31)||'TRUE'||chr(30)'''
p4_ = 'DO'

def create_PRF(p0_,p1_,p3_,p4_):
    print(p3_)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('XXXXXX.XX-1.local', '9999', service_name='DEV')
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'MY_USER_NAME', password='PASSWORD', dsn=dsn_tns)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.callproc('BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY_API.NEW__',[p0_,p1_,p3_,p4_] )
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

create_PRF(p0_,p1_,p3_,p4_)
```

The error that I am receiving is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "SPACE.py", line 40, in 
> create_PRF(p0_,p1_,p2_,p3_,p4_)
> File "SPACE.py", line 33, in create_PRF
> cur.callproc('BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY_API.NEW__',( p0_, p1_, p2_ , p3_ , p4_ ))
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY_API.NEW__' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: The error is pretty clear: Oracle can't find `BUSINESS_OPPORTUNITY_API.NEW__` in your database and that's the procedure you're telling it to call. We don't have access to your database, so it's hard to provide advice, but I'd suggest checking the spelling and access rights.